# Java Socket Corrupting PNG-image

Tags: java, image, sockets, transfer, corruption

I am currently trying to use a Socket to send a PNG or JPEG image from one Client to another (in Java) but the images always becomes corrupted (when I try to open it it just says that it can't be opened because it's damaged, faulty or too big). 
I have tried the methods that load the images into byte[] and if I just load an image into a byte[] and then save it back down it works perfectly so the problem must be in the sending of the byte[].
Here are the functions I use for the sending:

```
/**
 * Attempts to send data through the socket with the BufferedOutputStream. <p>
 * Any safety checks should be done beforehand
 * @param data - the byte[] containing the data that shall be sent
 * @return - returns 'true' if the sending succeeded and 'false' in case of IOException
 */
public boolean sendData(byte[] data){
    try {
        //We simply try to send the data
        outS.write(data, 0, data.length);
        outS.flush();
        return true;    //Success
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;   //Failed
    }
}

/**
 * Attempts to receive data sent to the socket. It uses a BufferedInputStream
 * @param size - the number of bytes that should be read
 * @return - byte[] with the received bytes or 'null' in case of an IOException
 */
public byte[] receiveData(int size){
    try {
        int read = 0, r;
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        do{
            //We keep reading until we have gotten all data
            r = inS.read(data, read, size-read);
            if(r > 0)read += r;
        }while(r>-1 && read<size);  //We stop only if we either hit the end of the 
                            //data or if we have received the amount of data we expected
        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The images that arrive seems to be the correct size and all so the data is at least arriving, just corrupted.

Comment: Please include what `outS` and `inS` are defined and what they are and how they are set.  What is the source code for when those are created?

Comment: have you tried reading the byte array using Apache Commons-IO's `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)` method?

Comment: I just made a program to compare each byte in the send images and I discovered that ALL the bytes in the sent image had been turned into zero!!   
I also want to add that the methods work perfectly if I'm sending a PDF, it can be read like normal upon arrival

Comment: inS = BufferedInputStream,
outS = BufferedOutputStream

Comment: how do you read the image byte data?

Comment: Tested sending a PDF with an image in it, that made it get corrupted too so it really is images that mess things up

Comment: You return a byte array full of zeros if you hit the end of stream.

Comment: you really should just use `IOUtils.toByteArray()` in your receive method

Comment: @Chikage No it isn't. Your code messes everything up. Not just images. Your code doesn't kow it's an image, and neither does TCP. Don't attribute magical properties to mechanical processes.

Comment: @EPJ I am not attributing magical properties to mechanical processes. I can only work with what I have. I have tried sending an image dozens of times, all became corrupt. I have also tried sending a PDF (with only text in it) dozens of times, not one of them became corrupt! What am I to assume? It simply works for my PDF but not for my image.

Comment: @EpicpandaForce What library is that? Do you have a short example of how to use it?

Comment: Yeah. It's *Apache Commons-IO* : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/ and the line is literally just `byte[] receivedData = IOUtils.toByteArray(yourInputStream);` and it can easily handle everything about reading the input stream into a byte array. It's simple and convenient!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am now using that library. The execution gets stuck at that exact line (byte[] receivedData = IOUtils.toByteArray(yourInputStream);) and doesn't continue

Comment: ...that is odd, are you using TCP? According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18723621/2413303 it should work without a problem. Is the connection even established and up?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am just using standard java sockets. Here's the way I initiate the socket and the method I use for sending/receiving http://pastie.org/9940332 and yes the connection is up and running. I'm sending text messages as a sort of "ping" before I start sending the files and those messages do get through (if they didn't the program wouldn't even try to send the file)

Comment: ....hmm, I'm stumped. I don't know why it's not working. Considering it is TCP, it should work.... IOUtils always worked for me with HTTP, and HTTP is just fancy TCP. I mean, socket TCP isn't too complicated https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Comment: By stating your code only corrupts images you are *ipso facto* attributing magical properties to it that it does not and cannot have. Nothing to debate there. Either the code corrupts everything or nothing, or something in between that depends on something it can know, such as file size modulo buffer size.

Comment: @EJP No I am not attributing "magical properties" to it. I once had a problem when trying to save a text file and it turned out corrupted (it changed the contents). I later found out that the method I called to save the file had a standard alphabet that was more restricted than the Strings in java which meant that I might have a few special characters in the String that didn't exist in that standard alphabet and therefore were reassigned to the character '?', corrupting the data.
Corruption can happen when special cases occur, it doesn't have to happen to "all or nothing" only.

Answer (score 3):

Throw your `receiveData()` method away and use `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Comment: I tried using that. Same result, the image failed (though it says that it's just 1 kB big now instead of the 9 MB it should be) and the PDF did get through but it is a few kB smaller (can still be opened, probably some text that got lost)

Comment: Then you didn't do it right. Post the code. It works for everybody else. It passes JDK QA, and has done for nearly 20 years.