# Reading a socket inputstream fully

Tags: java, android, sockets

Am trying to read all the reponse from a socket's `InputStream` and the total bytes to be read is **unknown**. Have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690954/java-how-to-read-an-unknown-number-of-bytes-from-an-inputstream-socket-socke) but none of the answer uses `DataInpuStream` so I tried coming up with one. This is what have done so far but I can't get the response from the socket. Am I doing something wrong? Any pointers?

**CODE**

```
public static String ReadFully(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    int bytesAvailable = din.available(); // is this right?
    din.readFully(buffer);
    return new String(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
}
```

**Calling method**

```
InputStream inputStream = outgoing.getInputStream();
String response = StreamReader.ReadFully(inputStream);
```

Comment: You need to design yourself a protocol so that you can tell when the whole message has been delivered.

Comment: Yes that is wrong because how can you fylly read 10000 bytes in a buffer of only 1024 bytes?

Comment: @greenapps Do you have a better approach?

Comment: Also you did not tell if the sender immediately closes the socket after having send that data or that it just stays in the air.

Comment: A better approach? You can see for yourself that your code is unsafe. So start to adapt that.